# How to display image one by one when taking array?

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iphone, I have all images in array but how to display one by one when I execute the array in a loop..

```
NSArray *images = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                        nil] retain];  


 int i=0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for ( NSString *imageName in images )
    {
        //NSTimer *timer=[[NSTimer alloc]init];
        UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        animalphoto = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        animalphoto.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        animalphoto.clipsToBounds = YES;



        animalphoto.animationDuration=5.0;
        animalphoto.animationRepeatCount=0;

        animalphoto.frame = CGRectMake( animalphoto.frame.size.width * i++, 0, animalphoto.frame.size.width, animalphoto.frame.size.height);


       width = animalphoto.frame.size.width;
        height = animalphoto.frame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"print:%@",image);
        [animalphoto release];
    }


}
```

Give any suggestion and sample code which is apply in our code..

Comment: Use this method :
`imgView.animationImages = images;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting one image just put whole array of images to the imgview.animationImages = images without the for loop

For further reference visit [this](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html) site.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `UIImageView's` object `animationImages` to set the `UIImage` array 
set `animationRepeatCount`
set `animationDuration` 
then call `[imageView startAnimating];` to start the animation